# Optimality of largest interval predicted by Picard's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we say that the largest interval of existence of the unique solution predicted by Picard's theorem is optimal to say that the problem has no unique solution outside the interval?

To make it clear, For the problem:
$\dfrac{\operatorname{dy}}{\operatorname{dx}}=y^2+\cos^2 x;x>0;y(0)=0$, Picard's largest interval of the existence of the unique solution is $J=[0,1/2]$,

My doubt: Can we say that the above problem has no unique solution outside $J$ directly from Picard's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing optimal in the standard proof of P-L. As most proofs in abstract calculus, or any other topic that is not explicitly numerical, the guiding principle is conceptual simplicity, not numerical efficiency. If numerical methods turn up at all, it is in their most basic and thus most simple versions. Thus the proof of the intermediate value theorem is based on the bisection method, the proof of the Cauchy-Peano theorem on the forward Euler method (or a variation thereof).

The interval length is restricted by the demand that the growth estimate for a solution remains inside the prescribed bounds. The standard construction is a bit circular and thus inefficient. First the rectangular box or cylindrical set is fixed with radii $a,b$, then the maximum absolute value $M_{a,b}$ of the ODE function is found, which gives in the worst case an early escape from the set at $h=b/M_{a,b}$. If this $h$ is smaller than $a$, the box needs to be reduced to this new radius to proceed with the construction.

In the presented example, one can find alternate bounds on the possible growth from $0\le y'\le 1+y^2$, which gives $|y(x)|\le \tan(|x|)$ for $|x|<\frac\pi2$. With this bound the proof construction can be carried out on any interval $[-a,a]$ with $a<\frac\pi2$. This is larger than your cited optimal $a=\frac12$.